# Application launched to a pink screen and a blank screen after built on Xcode and tested on Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, shader, testflight

I am creating a mobile game application using Unity software. I have already successfully uploaded it onto Google Playstore and there was totally no issues.

However, when I built my game on my MacBook using Xcode, there seems to be a major issue.

Everything was built successfully and after I tested the app on TestFlight, these are the issues that were occurring:

- Upon launch, screen was in a magenta/pink color
- Took few seconds to load then screen changed to a somewhat grey color
- Background music was playing
- I clicked certain buttons on the blank screen and it could bring me to the play mode (as I roughly know where the buttons are)

So the main issue is that nothing is showing on my screen but codes wise should be working fine.

I have tried resetting the graphics setting in unity and removed all storyboard related as I am not using any storyboards for launchscreen. I am using **Xcode 11.1** and tested on my iPhone X on the latest **iOS 13.2**

When I first submitted for Apple to review, it was rejected by saying that upon launch there was a blank screen and no information on how to resolve it was given to me

Comment: Do you mean the splash screen is pink?

Comment: I supposed so. Upon launch, I see a pink screen then it turns into a grey screen with background music playing

Comment: What is your graphics api?

Comment: I’m using the auto graphics API, default setting by Unity

Comment: Try to set Graphics API to metal.

Comment: I’m using MacBook so the default settings is set as Metal already

Comment: Same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This pink usually is caused by wrong shaders, especially if you are using asset bundle to load assets at runtime, you need to build different copies of asset bundles for different platforms and load the corresponding one.
It's recommended to build an empty project to test your environment, such like different version of Unity Editor, different rendering API settings and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to missing shaders in graphics settings of your project. reset shaders and your game will work fine, i found this effective in my case

Edit/ProjectSettings/Graphics. And Right Click at the top of the inspector page for built-in shaders and choose reset it should fix it for you automatically.

[image]